# Como obtener los amigos de un usuario?

Tags: spring, jpa

Como obtengo los amigos de un usuario?, el siguiente codigo es la clase User 
el cual tiene una lista de amigos  `Set<Friendship> friends = new HashSet<>();`
no se como obtener los amigos de los usuarios.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Friendship> friends = new HashSet<>();

    public User(){

    }
```

esta es la clase Friendship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Friendship")
public class Friendship implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("id")
    private User friend;

    public Friendship() {

    }

}
```

Como lleno esta lista `Set<Friendship> friends = new HashSet<>();`? para cuando pida los amigos de un usuario obtenga la lista.

Mi avance hasta el momento esta basada en 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633798/friend-relationships-with-jpa

**Edit 1: Definición de las tablas**

La tabla User tiene los datos personales de una persona

La tabla Friendship representa la amistad de un usuario con otro

los repositorios en realidad estan vacios

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

}

public interface FriendShipRepository extends Repository<Frienship, Long> {

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir la definición de las tablas?

Comment: @PabloLozano ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Me refería al SQL CREATE TABLE.... para saber los campos que había que mapear...

Comment: @PabloLozano estoy usando orm no estoy creando tablas desde sql

Comment: lo que estás preguntando es cómo hacer la query de jpa para traer la lista de amigos de un usuario?

Comment: @Blazerg si exacto, no se como obtener la lista de amigos que tiene un usuario

Comment: Podrías añadir a la pregunta el repositorio que usas para realizar las queries?

Comment: @Blazerg en realialidad estan vacios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a asumir que tu tabla Friendship tiene los siguiente campos:

```
id integer primary key
owner_id integer
friend_id integer
```

Y asumo que los dos últimos campos son FK que apuntan a la tabla User.

Por tanto, lo que tienes es una tabla auxiliar `frienship` que simplemente permite la relación *muchos a muchos* entre `Usuario` y `Usuario`. Esta tabla auxiliar realmente no necesitas *mapearla*, ya que podrías hacer algo como:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
      name = "Friendship", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id"), 
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id"))
    private Set<User> friends = new HashSet<>();

    public User(){

    }

    //getters y setters
}
```

Comment: para crear un usuario nuevo, el metodo create tiene como parametro un usuario asi: createUser(User userNew) entonces desde swagger me pide una lista de amigos, como lleno esa lista?

Comment: debo crear con una lista vacia verdad, luego voy agregando sus amigos a la lista

Comment: no deberia ser Set<Friendship> en lugar de Set<User>?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer no se puede hacer directamente dentro de jpa pues está diseñado (como parte del ORM) para trabajar con entidades, es decir, que la consulta sql que realice hibernate va a meterse dentro de una entidad y no puedes recoger directamente un campo específico de la entidad, pero si puedes recoger la entidad y luego acceder al atributo que quieras o usar proyecciones, veamos ambos ejemplos:

Dentro de tu interfaz UserRepository, la forma natural de hacer un "get by id" sería añadir el siguiente método:

```
User findById(Long Id);
```

Luego desde nuestros servicios podemos llamar a este método para recibir un usuario y luego acceder a la lista de amigos a través de su getter:

```
Set<Friendship> friends = UserRepository.findById(1).getFriends()
```

Si no quieres tener que usar la entidad al completo, no puedes usar métodos nativos de jpa pero otra opción es usar una proyección y añadir la consulta sql que quieras hacer, esto se hace con la etiqueta `@Query`, añadiendo otro método al repositorio:

```
 @Query("SELECT friends FROM users r where r.id = :1") 
 Set<Friendship> findFriendsByUserIde(@Param("id") Long id); //el param es posible que pueda omitirse dependiendo de tu versión de jpa.
```

Entre estos dos enfoques yo prefiero el primero porque el código es mucho más limpio y no es más eficiente que lo segundo a no ser que tengas muchas columnas en tu tabla y que el servidor tarde mucho tiempo en serializar cada entidad.

EDIT: otro motivo por el que prefiero el primer enfoque es porque en caso de cambiar algo en tu entidad, el método va a seguir funcionando perfectamente ya que los atributos vienen de la entidad, en el segundo caso puede ocurrir que tengas que cambiar la entidad y también la query ya que hibernate no te va a saber analizar los métodos de tu repositorio ni te va a devolver errores de compilación por haber alterado una entidad y el método dentro del repositorio (y si tienes muchos `@Query` es muy probable que la gente se olvide de actualizarlos al cambiar una entidad).